# Unable to verify dictionary integer value using 'in' operator

Tags: dictionary, python-3.7

I'm getting False when I try to check if 7 is there in the dictionary:

> > > spam = {'name': 'Zophie', 'age': 7}
> > > 'age' in spam
> > > True
> > > 'name' in spam
> > > True
> > > 7 in spam
> > > False

Can anybody advise what's wrong with code as it worked for other keys and values?

Comment: Hello ! 
Could you provide us more proper code that you've tried so for ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed,  the `in` checks only in the keys. Do `'Zophie' in spam.values()` or
`7 in spam.values()`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you, Nach. Looks like I missed the point that it only iterated on keys, not values.